# How to embed HTML with PHP array in e-mail message?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to send an email whith the order details after visitor submit the order. I am trying to embed my order array result in a html tag but it is not working. Help please

senmail.php

```
<?php

$to = "member@yahoo.com";
$from = "sales@thesite.com"; 
$headers = "From: $from";
$subject = "Custom computer Order Confirmation Nunber_ $orderid";
$message = " 
 <html>
 <body>
   <p> This doesn't render well</p> 
   <table style="margin-left:50px; text-align:left;">
     <tr>
       <th style="width:20%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000;">Item ID</th>
       <th style="width:40%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000">Description</th>
       <th style="width:15%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000">Quantity</th>
       <th style="width:20%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000">Unit Price</th>
     </tr>  

   <?php 
     foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"]as $item): 
        $item_id=$item['part_id'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM   product_description        
        WHERE product_id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");

        While($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $product_name=$row["name"];      
     }   
   ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $item['part_id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product_name ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['quantity'] ?></td>     
    <td><?php echo $item['price'] ?></td>
  </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
</body>
</html> 
 ";
 $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

.........

?>
```

Comment: please define "not working"

Comment: What is the exact problem ? are there any errors or is it just not working ?

Comment: What do you have in `$message`? Did you have start session?

Comment: @Brotheyura in $message is the html/php code

Comment: Note The mail client is no even rendering the html code. i also gust I should define a variable for my array but don't know how if this is the solution.

Comment: @user3412978 Does the email arrive ?

Comment: the syntax is wrong all over the place you should be getting errors

Comment: Like @Dagon said, there are many syntax errors. Try to put commas at the end of each echo on the table for starters.

Comment: html is displaying like this `<html><body><p>not rendering</p></html></body>`  and my table is trowing bunch of errors But I know my foreach works well since I use the same code to display on the web page.

Comment: What `$mailsent` returns ?? try send mail `mail('member@yahoo.com', 'the subject', 'Hello');` and check in email.

Comment: @user3412978 email arrive if I remove the table

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're not escaping the quotes in `$message`. use `'` or `\"` for html instead. Also you don't need the extra PHP tags in the middle of `$message` as you're still writing in PHP. Inside your `foreach` concatenate `$message` with `.=` and by the end it will be a string which you can submit with your email. I haven't tested it but I cleaned up your code and made the suggested changes below.

```
$message = " 
    <html>
        <body>
            <p> This doesn't render well</p> 
            <table style="margin-left:50px; text-align:left;">
                <tr>
                ...
```

Should be

```
$message = " 
    <html>
        <body>
            <p> This doesn't render well</p> 
            <table style=\"margin-left:50px; text-align:left;\">
                <tr>
                ...
```

Here you go

```
<?php

$to = "member@yahoo.com";
$from = "sales@thesite.com"; 
$headers = "From: $from";
$subject = "Custom computer Order Confirmation Nunber_ $orderid";
$message = "<html>
            <body>
                <p>This doesn't render well</p>
                <table style=\"margin-left:50px; text-align:left;\">
                    <tr>
                        <th style=\"width:20%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000\">Item ID</th>
                        <th style=\"width:40%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000\">Description</th>
                        <th style=\"width:15%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000\">Quantity</th>
                        <th style=\"width:20%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000\">Unit Price</th>
                    </tr>";

foreach( $_SESSION["cart_array"] as $item )
{
    $item_id = $item["part_id"];
    $sql     = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM product_decsription WHERE product_id='".$item_id."' LIMIT 1;" );

    if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $message .= "
                    <tr><td>".$item['part_id']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                        <td>".$item['quantity']."</td>     
                        <td>".$item['price']."</td></tr>";
    }
}

$message .= "</table></body></html>";
$mailsent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

?>
```

**EDIT:** the headers to use html need to be:

```
$headers  = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Comment: Nevermind the fact that they're trying to execute PHP code embedded in a string?

Comment: Her is the result I am getting with this. Data is in now but no table and all html tag are showing.
 `<html>
 <body>
 <p>This doesn't render well</p>
<table style="margin-left:50px; text-align:left;">
 <tr>
 <th style="width:20%; ...</th>
 <th style="width:40%; ..</th>
  <th style="width:15%; ..</th>
  <th style="width:20%; ..</th>
   </tr>
  <tr><td>34</td>
  <td>Intel Core i3-4130 Haswell 3.4GHz LGA1150l</td>
 <td>2</td>   
 <td>0.0000</td><td>36</td>
 <td>Intel Core i3-4130  </td>
 <td>1</td>   
<td>0.0000</td></tr></table></body></html>`

Comment: Also, rows seams to be showing in one line instate of 1 row/ item.

Comment: That is because you now need to update your headers to reflect the content type of the `$message` try this:

`$headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";`

Check this page out: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: Ah yeah, the <tr> needs to be inside the foreach loop.

Comment: You are right the html is rendering now and I can see the table. But the issue now is with the table. the second row shows as 5th colum not on the following line.

Comment: Check the code of the answer, I have updated it to show where the `<tr>` for each row should be

Comment: Absolutely perfect. It is working very well. Thank you soooo much. I spend 2 days on this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

bored enough to fix it all for you:

```
<?php

$to = "member@yahoo.com";
$from = "sales@thesite.com";
$headers = "From: $from";
$subject = "Custom computer Order Confirmation Nunber_ $orderid";
$message = '
 <html>
 <body>
   <p> This doesn\'t render well</p>
   <table style="margin-left:50px; text-align:left;">
     <tr>
       <th style="width:20%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000;">Item ID</th>
       <th style="width:40%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000">Description</th>
       <th style="width:15%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000">Quantity</th>
       <th style="width:20%; border-bottom:solid 1px #000">Unit Price</th>
     </tr>';


foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $item){
    $item_id = $item['part_id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM   product_description
        WHERE product_id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");

    While ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql) ){
        $product_name = $row["name"];
    }

    $message .= '
  <tr>
    <td>'.$item['part_id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$product_name.'</td>
    <td>'.$item['quantity'].'</td>
    <td>'.$item['price'].'</td>
  </tr>';
}

$message .= '  </table>
</body>
</html>';


$mailsent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

//.........


?>
```

i only fixed the basics, this is still **far from ideal**

Comment: Yep, upvote. I would also change the query from ""SELECT * FROM product_description..." to ""SELECT name FROM product_description..." as it is bizarre to query thhe whole table for each order when you only need a name.  Not to mention that product name should also come from the session like the rest of the info (or alternatevily all should come from the db).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed PHP code inside strings and magically have it execute.

The correct approach would be to store the message in a string and use a processing loop to add to it.  Such a result would look like:

```
$msg = "Beginning of message\n";
foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"]as $item) {
    $item_id=$item['part_id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM   product_description        
    WHERE product_id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $product_name = $row["name"];
        $msg .= "<td>$product_name</td>";
        // Other message parts go here
    } 
$msg .= "End of message\n";
```

Alternately, you can go a very terrible route and use something like [eval](https://www.php.net/eval), but because I discourage such behavior I will not be providing an example.